# Is there a word for when a word changes from a noun to a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

I searched the Internet, but I couldn't find anything. What would be a good term in linguistics to describe the transition of, say, the noun "yo-yo" as in "I like the yo-yo" to the verb "yo-yo" as in "I like to yo-yo"? These transitions are very common in English, and I never found a term to apply to it. Any help?

Comment: Check out [this puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf) for openers.

Comment: Whatever the word is, it's likely to be a verb. Unless you use it as a noun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Anthimeria**: ***Using one part of speech as another part of speech, such as using a noun as if it were a verb:***

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria)

> In rhetoric, anthimeria, traditionally and more properly called
>   antimeria (from the Greek: ἀντί, antí, "against, opposite" and μέρος,
>   méros, "part"), involves using one part of speech as another part of
>   speech, such as using a noun as if it were a verb: "The little old
>   lady turtled along the road." Using a noun as a verb has become so
>   common that many nouns have actually become verbs also. For example,
>   "Let's book the flight." The noun "book" is now often used as a verb,
>   as in this example. Other noun-as-verb usages include "I can keyboard
>   that for you," "We need to scissor expenses," and "Desk him." Other
>   substitutions could include an adjective used as a noun, as in "She
>   dove into the foaming wet," interjection as verb, as in "Don't aha
>   me!" a verb as a noun, as in "Help! I need some eat!" and so on.

**Verbification, or verbin**g, is the creation of a verb from a noun, adjective or other word.

***In linguistics this kind of word formation is termed as*** [**Conversion or Zero derivation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verbification)

> "In linguistics, conversion, also called zero derivation, is a kind of
>   word formation involving the creation of a word (of a new word class)
>   from an existing word (of a different word class) without any change
>   in form,[3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verbalize) which is to say, derivation using only zero. For example,
>   the noun green in golf (referring to a putting-green) is derived
>   ultimately from the adjective green.
>
> Conversions from adjectives to nouns and vice versa are both very
>   common and unnotable in English; much more remarked upon is the
>   creation of a verb by converting a noun or other word (e.g., the
>   adjective clean becomes the verb to clean)".

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it is 'verbification' or 'verbing' if creating a verb from other forms.

Answer (score 5):

The Wikipedia article on [Conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)) says that **verbification** or **verbing** is the creation of a verb from a noun, adjective or other word."

I would not use **verbalise/ize** in this sense, as to me that means "to put into words". But judging from the other answers, some people do use it that way.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of terms that are used. A number of these terms refer to the process of becoming a verb: verbalization, verbification, verbing (see the tag [verbing](/questions/tagged/verbing)). But there's also a term for the process of changing a noun:

### Denominalization

> A very common operation that applies to nouns is denominalization. The term nominal can be translated "noun-like;" so to denominalize something is to make it less noun-like, or turn it into a verb, adjective, or some other grammatical category.
>   <sub>[Describing Morphosyntax: A Guide for Field Linguists](https://books.google.com/books?id=LC3DfjWfCiwC&pg=PA94)</sub>

By extension, you call the resulting verbs **denominal verbs**.